# What ways can a Consumer consume message in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

If there is a Kafka server "over there" somewhere across the network I would assume that there might be two ways that a Consumer could consume the messages:

1. By first of all 'subscribing' to the Topic and in effect telling the Kafka server where it is listening so that when a new message is Produced, Kafka proactively sends the message to the Consumer, across the network.
2. The Consumer has to poll the Kafka server asking for any new messages, using the offset of the messages it has currently taken.

Is this how Kafka works, and is the option configurable for which one to use?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Kafka only supports option 2. But that's just from my experience. Here is the basic documentation on consumers. http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers

Answer (score 3):

I'm expanding my comment into an answer.

Reading through the [consumer documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers), Kafka only supports option 2 as you've described it. It is the consumers responsibility to get messages from the Kafka server. In the 0.9.x.x Consumer this is accomplished by the [poll() method](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html). The Consumer polls the Kafka Server and returns messages if there are any. There are several reasons I believe they've chosen to avoid supporting option 1.

1. It limits the complexity needed in the Kafka Server. It's not the Server's responsibility to push messages to a consumer, it just holds the messages and waits till a consumer fetches them.
2. If the Kafka Server was pushing all messages to the consumers, it could overwhelm a consumer. Say a Producer was pushing messaging into a Kafka Server 10 msg/sec, but a certain Consumer could only process 2 msg/sec. If the Kafka Server attempted to push every message it received to that Consumer, the Consumer would quickly be overwhelmed by the number of messages it receives.

There's probably other reasons, but at the moment those were the two I thought about.

Comment: In the perspective of the consumer to poll the kafka msg broker or server, what would the ideal or recommended ways to implement in .net world? One approach comes to my mind is windows services but are there any other solutions/approaches? wanted to brainstorm on other options besides on-prem/windows services only.